# A question about the integral representation of Bessel functions.

Tags: bessel-functions

I have a question about Bessel functions,
I know that the integral representation of the Bessel function of the first kind is:

$J_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta) \,d\theta$

Now, what is this integral?

$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta) \,d\theta$

Is it related to Bessel functions? Or is it something else entirely?

*Sidenote*: I’ve also seen this:

$J_n(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta) \,d\theta$

What is the difference between this integral and the one I wrote above?

Thank you.